# Problema con validar usuarios bloqueados Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un sitio el cual tengo una funcion para validar si el correo ingresado pertenece o no a un usuario en lista negra *(Usuario Bloqueado).* El cual para le caso que se cumpla no debe permitir enviar le formulario.

Lo que debería hacer la validación es, validar si el correo ingresado es igual a algún correo de un usuario que está en la lista negra. Para obtener ese correo la validacion preguntara primero si el **id del usuario** de mi **TABLA ListaNegra**, es igual al **id** de mi **tabla usuario** y finalmente preguntará si el correo de ese usuario es igual al correo recibido desde el formulario.

Como por ejemplo, la siguiente consulta me muestra los usuarios que tengo en la lista negra, es decir, bloqueados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir la validacion debe seguir de manera similar el mismo orden de la consulta, más el correo recibido desde el formulario.

Este es el formulario.

```
<form name="form" action="{{route('miruta')}} method="POST">

  @foreach($user as $user)
    @foreach($lista_negra as $lista)
      @if($lista->user_id == $user->id)
         <input type="hidden" id="user_email" value="{{$user->email}}">
         <input type="hidden" id="user_name" value="{{$user->name}}">
      @endif
    @endforeach
  @endforeach

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Responsable</td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" name="responsable" id="responsable" required="required">

        <br><br>
        <textarea maxlength="500" id="comentario" name="comentario"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
       <!--CONTENIDO-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" name="guardar" id="btn-guardar" value="CONFIRMAR"/>
</form>
```

He estado probando en realizar la validacion en mi controlador, de la siguiente manera:

```
public function guardarReserva(Request $request){

  $monto = $request->codigo;

  if($request->isMethod('POST')){

    $id_complejo=$request->input('complejo');
    $horario=$request->input('horario');
    $indumentarias=$request->input('indumentaria');
    $responsable=$request->input('responsable');
    $fono_responsable=$request->input('fono_responsable');
    $comentario = $request->input('comentario');

    $id_descuento=0;
    $fecha_reserva=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    $listaNegra = DB::select('select users.email from lista_negra join users where lista_negra.user_id like users.id');


    //CONDICION - ¿COMO PODRIA COMPARAR EL ARRAY $listaNegra?
    if ($listaNegra == $responsable) {

        Session::flash('error', 'El usuario'.' '.$user_name.' '.'no se puede utilizar como responsable debido a que se encuentra en Lista Negra');
        return Redirect()->back();
    } 

    //SEGUNDA FORMA
    $user_blocked = $request->user_email;

    if($user_blocked == $responsable){
      Session::flash('error', 'Este usuario no se puede utilizar porque se encuentra bloqueado');
    return redirect()->back();
    }

    //AL HACER UN dd($user_blocked == $responsable) OBTENGO true COMO RESULTADO


    //VISTA FINAL QUE ES RETORNADA
    return view('reservar-cancha-exito',['id'=>$rid,'hora_inicio'=>$hora_inicio,'complejo'=>$complejo,'hora_fin'=>$hora_fin,'monto'=>$monto,'cancha'=>$cancha,'descuento'=>$monto_descuento,'fecha_reserva' => $fecha_reserva,'indumentarias' => $indumentariasArr]);
  }

}
```

El cual al realizar un **`dd($listaNegra, $responsable)`** obtengo lo siguiente:

> **IMPORTANTE:** La foto está editada para explicar cuál es el correo recibido por la variable **`$request`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente la validacion no funciona de ninguna de las 2 formas. Y no recibo ningún error, para el primer caso en cambio para el segundo recibo un error que dice **`NO MESSAGE`.**

¿Que podría haber hecho mal? Como información extra dejo **los modelos principales** que ocupo.

El modelo para la **lista negra.**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ListaNegra extends Model{

  protected $table = "lista_negra";
  protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
?>
```

Y el modelo del **usuario.**

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

  class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract,CanResetPasswordContract{

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['id','name', 'email', 'password','LastName','sLastName','telephone','role_id', 'complejo_id'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($valor){
        if (!empty($valor)){
            $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($valor);
        }
    }
  }
?>
```

También he probado en la vista de la siguiente manera, sin obtener el resultado esperado, el cual es mostrar una alerta al usuario impidiendo que se envíe el formulario.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var name_user = document.getElementById('user_name').val();

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-guardar').click(function(){
      $("#user_email").each(function(e){

        var user_mail = $('#user_email').val();
        var email_usuario= document.getElementById('responsable').value;

        if(email_usuario == user_mail){
           e.prevenDefault();
           $('#responsable').focus();

           $.alert({
            title: ''+'<nav style="background: #478573; color: white; width: 20cm;height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top:2.5mm; padding-bottom: 6mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Error!</nav> ',
            content: ''+'<label style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">El usuario (@'+name_user+') no se puede utilizar ya que se encuentra bloqueado.</label>',
          });
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: y dondes estas ejecutando la función?

Comment: Hay que ir por partes para resolver tu problema, ¿dónde tienes guardada la lista negra de corres?

Comment: Es otra vista aparte, en ella se va creando la lista negra, la cual va a una tabla llamada **lista_negra**. En concreto yo  valido preguntando a la tabla `lista_negra` de mi BD como primer paso. Por eso los primeros `@foreach()` en el input que puse en los `@foreach()` traigo los usuarios que se encuentran en la lista negra y muestro su correo. El correo viene de otra tabla llamada **users**

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, ahora que vas a hacer todo en el controlador, es necesario ver como están modelos, así es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Volvi a editar la pregunta añadiendo los modelos que ocupo, obviamente hay más pero deje los más importantes que ocupo para la validacion que quiero implementar.

Comment: Bien, el usuario envió "pedro@gmail" y ese correo está en tu lista negra, ¿Cierto?

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz. Así es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta, he logrado solucionar el dilema. Lo que hice fue realizar la validacion en el controlador antes de guardar los datos recibidos.

- Primero puse unos campos con unos valores, que se validarán después en el controlador.

---

```
<!--PUEDEN ESTAR COMO HIDDEN LOS INPUT COMO TAMBIEN DARLE COMO ESTILO UN DISPLAY: NONE-->
@foreach($user as $user)
    @foreach($listaNegra as $lista)
        @if($lista->user_id == $user->id)
            <!-- USUARIOS EN LISTA NEGRA -->
            <input type="text" id="user_email" readonly="readonly" name="user_email" value="{{$user->email}}" style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" id="user_id_input" name="user_id_input">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$lista->user_id}}" id="listaNegra" name="listaNegra">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->name}}" id="user_name">
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Los campos son el `email` del usuario, el `id` del usuario, y el `id` del usuario en la **lista negra,** respectivamente.

Luego en el controlador rescate los datos a validar y le aplique la validacion que retorna a mi pagina principal en caso de que se cumpla con un mensaje de error.

```
public function guardarReserva(Request $request){

    $monto = $request->codigo;

    if($request->isMethod('POST')){

        $id_complejo=$request->input('complejo');
        $horario=$request->input('horario');
        $indumentarias=$request->input('indumentaria');

        $responsable = $request->input('responsable');

        $fono_responsable=$request->input('fono_responsable');
        $comentario = $request->input('comentario');

        $id_descuento=0;

        $fecha_reserva=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //VALIDACION
        $lista = $request->listaNegra;
        $usuario_b = $request->user_id_input;
        $user_email = $request->user_email; 


        if ($lista == $usuario_b && $user_email == $responsable) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Este usuario se encuentra bloqueado por lo que no se puede utilizar como responsable');

            return Redirect()->route('reservar'); //PAGINA INICIO RESERVAS
       }

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El tener varios `foreach` en la vista es demasiada carga para el servidor, hagámoslo vía `javascript`:

1.- Elimina tus `foreach` de la vista.

2.- Ya tenemos las variable `$lista_negra`, suponiendo que es un array hacemos esto en el `Javascript`:

```
function ValidaEmail(e){
...
    var listaNegra  = {{ $listaNegra }};
    var responsable = document.getElementById('responsable').value;
    var a           = listaNegra.indexOf(responsable);
    if ( a != -1 ) //significa que sí encontró el correo en la lista negra
    {
       //Muestras la alerta de que el correo no se puede usar
       $.alert({
          title: ''+'<nav style="background: #478573; color: white; width: 20cm;height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top:2.5mm; padding-bottom: 6mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Error!</nav> ',
          content: ''+'<label style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">No se puede usar a este usuario como responsable ya que se encuentra bloqueado.</label>',
        });
        e.prevenDefault();
        $('#responsable').focus();
        return:
    }
    // **Aqui pones el código que deberá ejecutarse si el correo NO está en la lista negra**
...
}
```

**Nota**: Si la función `indexOf` no encuentra el valor dentro del array devuelve `-1`.

**Nota2**: La función `indexOf` es `caseSensitive`.

**Nota 3**:La función `indexOf` se añadió en `JavaScript 1.6` y no funciona en `IE 8` y versiones anteriores.

**Nota 4**: `{{$listaNegra }}` solo funcionará si `Script` está dentro de la vista `Blade` y no en un archivo externo.

Comment: ¿por que no te funciona? Si ahora estás probando eso entonces edita tu pregunta, por que indicas que lo quieres hacer en la vista no en el controlador.

Comment: Yo escogería hacerlo del lado del controlador, es más fácil.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con este script ya que la parte php del blucle no la has explicado muy bien

```
function ValidaEmail(e){

    // OBTENEMOS EL INPUT PRINCIPAL A VALIDAR
    var responsable = $("input#responsable").val();


    // OBTENEMOS EL OTRO INPUT A VALIDAR

    $("input[name='user_email']").each(function(i,item){
          var u_email = $(item).val();

    //  VALIDAMOS SI EL VALOR DEL PRIMER INPUT ES IGUAL A 
    //  ALGUNO DEL 2DO INPUT
          if(responsable == u_email){
             e.prevenDefault();
             $('#responsable').focus();

             $.alert({
          title: ''+'<nav style="background: #478573; color: white; width: 20cm;height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top:2.5mm; padding-bottom: 6mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Error!</nav> ',
          content: ''+'<label style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">No se puede usar a este usuario como responsable ya que se encuentra bloqueado.</label>',
      })
          }
     });

  }
```

Comment: No funciona aquello amigo, igual envía el formulario.